# Cannot find module 'node-static'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run samples regarding webrtc. For that I went to

https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab/src/50a47bb092483fd7ca27998a365dff434919bf89?at=master

At step 5 I needed to run server.js. For that I opened my Windows Command prompt and entered:

**C:\Program Files\nodejs>node D:\GITProjects\codelab\complete\step5\server.js**

But I got this error:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^ Error: Cannot find module 'node-static'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\GITProjects\codelab\complete\step5\server.js:1:76)

    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

I have already installed node-static module and it is present at

"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\node-static"

[image]

Still I am getting the error "Cannot find module 'node-static'".

Environmental "PATH" variable is set to "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm"

I can see the node-static folder is present at "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-static" path too.

**Edit**:

Based on the comments I tried this on Windows Command Prompt to install node-static:

**C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install node-static -g**

I got this as the output:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\static -> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\node-static\bin\cli.js
node-static@0.7.6 C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-static
├── mime@1.3.4
├── colors@1.1.2
└── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
```

Can you help me location the cause of my issue?

Comment: Could you please try installing node-static globally in the command line: `npm install node-static -g`. Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Or try to install using npm install node-static --save-dev

Comment: Answer edited. Ran :npm install node-static -g:. Ran both commands but still the same error.

Comment: Solution I found:
Run Node.js command prompt instead of Windows Command prompt. Cd to  the root directory where package.json is, in my case "D:\GITProjects\codelab\complete>npm install"

Comment: you and I literally are going through the same tutorial, except 6 mo's apart... crazy.  internet brain twins. Thanks for asking this question, helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

`node_static` is not an inbuilt nodejs module so there should be a folder `node_modules` in your doc root folder(step5) with this module in it or create a `package.json` and list it as a dependency then run `npm install` before `node server.js`

Comment: Sorry for asking noob question but can you point me how to got my root directory and run npm install?

Comment: just run `npm install node-static` in the folder `step5'

Answer (score 1):

just run `npm install` on cd into the "complete" directory i.e `codelab\complete`